# Javascript : how to count new lines in textarea ou conteneditable div?

Tags: javascript, count, textarea, newline

when I type a long text in textarea (or in a conteneditable div), the textarea create automatically break lines (without typing Enter key) when the long text exceed the textarea width.

So, how I can count new lines ?

Thank you in advance, cordially.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to calculate the line height of the lines, then divide the full height of the text area by the line height.

Of course, in that case you would need to remove the re-size option on the text area and have it auto-resize. It's difficult because of the auto-resize option, so generally the best way to do it is to set very specific sizes on the text area so that you can duplicate and calculate based on the strings.